# How to use backchannel in Node.js when working with Azure Bot Service SDK V4

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm currently working on a chat bot (in SDK V4) where I need to send an activity to the chat client as an event. According to the documentation I could do it like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) in SDK V3 using the backchannel mechanism but when switching to the documentation for SDK V4 I can not find anything about it. How would I go about doing this in SDK V4?

Answer (score 1):

### Understanding Backchannel vs Bot SDK

`Backchannel` is something related to the `Webchat` channel, it is not related to the Bot SDK version.

So it will depend on the Webchat "version", not the Bot SDK version: Webchat is a side project which is developed here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

There are also version of Webchat (v3 vs v4) but these versions are not directly linked to Bot Builder version (v3 and v4 also): you can use Webchat v3 with Bot v3 OR Bot v4.

### Using Backchannel

For the backchannel feature, both v3 and v4 of the Webchat have this ability, but in a different way of coding:

- v3 sample here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/v3/samples/backchannel/index.html
- v4 sample here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event

Then on your bot you have to handle those events

Comment: the second link's resource is not found